# url of GET request is exceeding the max character limit

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, get

we are generating url for get request on basis of data i receive from different calls. Some request`s Url is exceeding the maximum character limit of get request. is there a way to reduce the size of url and also to send all data received.

I did find anything regarding this
`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` 
the length of url is generally greater than 6000 characters

Comment: it would be better if you share one example URL so I can check what type of data you are passing to generate the URL and then can suggest you a solution.

Comment: "*we are generating url*" - if *you* are generating the URL - and the problem is the length of it - then *you* need to change the structure/conventions used by your URLs. You haven't said what the length in characters is, or given an example, but in principle the only way around the problem is reducing the length.

Comment: i have edited the post and added the url

Comment: The "*url*" provided is not a url. It appears to be data/information. If you just want to shorten it, that heavily depends on what the data is. You would either want to change how the data is generated or use some sort of compression algorithm on it. Alternatively, I'm curious why you are sending data in a GET request, rather than POST, which would be more fitting for transmitting data to a server.

Comment: i have just joined the org, i also dont know the reason @EssXTee